# How can I use a swift package in python?

Tags: python, swift, xcode, xcodebuild, swift-package-manager

I am trying to interface Swift functions to Python. Python can interpret any `@_cdecl` functions in a `.dylib`.

For a project directory with a single Swift source:

```
project/
    test.swift
    test.py
```

I can run `swiftc test.swift -emit-library` to generate a .dylib file.

More advanced, using a Swift Package, it looks like this:

```
project/
    TestPackage/
        ...
    test.py
```

In my Swift Package, I can pass the `-emit-library` parameter to the Swift Compiler within swift build like such: `swift build -Xswiftc -emit-library`. This exports my package to a .dylib.

My problem is adding dependencies to my package. I added the SwifterSwift package as a dependency just to test, and ran `swift build -Xswiftc -emit-library`. I got this error:

```
swift build -Xswiftc -emit-library
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_$s10Foundation4DateV12SwifterSwiftE11weekOfMonthSivg", referenced from:
      _$s11TestPackage6swiftyyyF in TestPackage.swift.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, it looks like SwifterSwift exported a .dylib successfully. But my main project, TestPackage did not. `swift build` did work on its own, but does not reach my goal for generating a .dylib.

**Question:**

How can I get the whole package to compile as .dylib with dependencies? Am I missing a linker command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of experimenting with `swift build` and `swiftc` variations, I found the much easier solution:

In the manifest, set type to dynamic.

`.library(name: "TestPackage", type: .dynamic, targets: ["TestPackage"]),`

After `swift build` (no fancy parameters), the .dylib is found at:

`TestPackage/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx/debug/libTestPackage.dylib`

Now I can use some Swift Packages in Python!